# Using wget but only getting html files

Tags: file, download, wget, netcdf

I am trying to download multiple NETCDF files from NASA website.

So I was following their tutorial of how to download multiple files using wget for windows(https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/data-access#windows_wget).

When I try to use the option to dowload multiple data files at once, the output is only returning to me html files and not the netcdf files. Does anyone know what can be happening?

Ps.: I am executing with the following command:

```
wget --load-cookies C:\.urs_cookies --save-cookies C:\.urs_cookies --auth-no-challenge=on --keep-session-cookies --user=<your username> --ask-password --content-disposition -i <url.txt>
```

Comment: Looks like this is not recursive. Try adding "-r"

Comment: What is the content of your html files ? you might have an error within them such as 404, 401 or 403.